# Mysqli conn include file - global variable PHP

Tags: php, global-variables, class-constructors

I'm including the MySQLi connection file in the constructor of a PHP class. Since I need to reach the connect variable in methods in this class I need to make the variable global. I always heard global variables are bad. So I wonder, is this the only/best way to deal with this?

```
class CheckUser {

  function __construct() {
     require_once('mysqli.php');
  }

  function checkEmail($email) {
     // sql code here
  }

}
```

Comment: I don't get the point. Do you need the connection **outside** the class? If not, why should it not be available to the methods?

Comment: I need to call methods as "free standing" methods, so to speak..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just a meme. (And dependency injection is coming right up...)

Your connection handle is a central resource. Use it as such. A global variable is perfectly fine and the intended langauge construct for that. It makes sense as long as you only have *one* database / connection.

If global variables were bad, we wouldn't have `$_GET` and `$_POST` (which are *actual* global variables).

Should your class (guessing here) be the central access point to database queries, then keeing the handle as simple property is just as cromulent.

```
  function __construct() {
     require_once('mysqli.php');
     $this->db = $db;
  }
```

Or whatever local variable the `mysqli.php` script created.

Comment: Ok, what about using the reference to the variable in a field in the class then? I'm unsure how to do it in PHP though, but shouldn't that be just as good?

Comment: For resource handles it doesn't matter if it's a copy or a variable reference. -- More concrete answers can often be had if you post current code excerpts.

Comment: Still hard to say without knowing what your connection file does in practice.